# Derivation of an Instance of Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

In the William Lane Craig VS Bart Ehrman [debate](https://youtu.be/K2NEiW69G-0?t=2641), Dr. Craig presents the formula $Pr(R\ |\ (B\ \cap\ E)) = \frac{Pr(R\ |\ B)\ Pr(E\ |\ (B\ \cap\ R))}{Pr(R\ |\ B)\ Pr(E\ |\ (B\ \cap\ R)) + Pr(R^c\ |\ B)\ Pr(E\ |\ (B\ \cap\ R^c))}$. *(notation slightly modified)*

The forms of Bayes' Theorem of which I'm familiar are the probability form, $Pr(X\ |\ Y) = \frac{Pr(X)\ Pr(Y\ |\ X)}{Pr(Y)}$, and the odds form, $\frac{Pr(X\ |\ Y)}{Pr(X^c\ |\ Y)} = \frac{Pr(X)}{Pr(Y)} \frac{Pr(Y\ |\ X)}{Pr(X^c\ |\ Y)}$.

The most progress I can make using my understanding of Bayes' Theorem is $Pr(R\ |\ (B\ \cap\ E)) = \frac{Pr(R)\ Pr((B\ \cap\ E)\ |\ R)}{Pr(B\ \cap\ E)} = \frac{Pr(R)\ Pr((B\ \cap\ E)\ |\ R)}{Pr(B)\ Pr(E\ |\ B)}$.  How can I get from here to the formula from the debate, $\frac{Pr(R\ |\ B)\ Pr(E\ |\ (B\ \cap\ R))}{Pr(R\ |\ B)\ Pr(E\ |\ (B\ \cap\ R)) + Pr(R^c\ |\ B)\ Pr(E\ |\ (B\ \cap\ R^c))}$?

Comment: Aren't those two guys, uh, theologians?

Comment: @Renard I believe they both have PhDs in Theology, yeah.  I would have called Ehrman an atheologian, but am now seeing conflicting definitions of the word.

Comment: What does "around 44:00" mean?

Comment: @RobArthan Just the time in the debate video when the Bayes' Theorem formula was invoked, for anyone curious enough to search.

Comment: I see: I would have understood if you'd included a link to the video, As things stood, I wondered whether one of these guys wanted to institute a 48 hour clock). There is no such word as "atheologian" and I don't think this is a good topic for MSE. Mathematics has been abused by religious fanatics over the years for many purposes. Here on MSE, let's agree just to do mathematics and to take our religious concerns to more appropriate places.

Comment: @RobArthan: It's pretty risky to say something isn't a word when it shows up attested in a number of places, but I agree that this isn't the right place to introduce such aspects of a discussion.  I'm recommending the OP edit the post down to eliminate those details; they aren't needed to address the central question.

Comment: OP: Please edit the question (including the title) to remove these details; the question can be addressed without them.

Comment: @RobArthan I updated the question to include the link.  With all due respect, I think it should be obvious to anyone who reads this question that "religious concern" is an unreasonable way to characterize it.  It is not opinion-based, as the current vote suggests, but instead asks for the derivation of a mathematical formula.  The resurrection debate was only mentioned for context, as one might reference a particular math book which contains elements of their question.  Mathematics intersects with philosophy of religion and Scripture scholarship in a number of ways.

Comment: To suggest that asking questions near these points of contact is not "do[ing] mathematics" seems arbitrary.

Comment: @BrianTung I have edited the title accordingly, though I think retaining the reference in the question adds helpful context.

Comment: `@BrianTung: I see that there are attested uses of "atheologian", but I can't say I think much of them.  However, we don't have to worry about that now in the context of this MSE post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of conditional probability:

$$P(X | Y) = \frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)} $$

A property of conditional probability is that if we take a theorem and replace the probabilities with probabilities conditional on some other event $B$, then the relationship still holds:

$$P(X | Y \cap B) = \frac{P(X \cap Y | B)}{P(Y | B)}$$

Of note here is that the conditional replacement of $P(X | Y)$ is $P(X | Y \cap B)$, since a probability being conditional on both $Y$ and $B$ is the same as being conditional on their intersection.

We can apply the same principle to Bayes' Theorem (this following immediately from the above):

$$P(X | Y \cap B) = \frac{P(Y | X \cap B)P(X | B)}{P(Y | B)}$$

Replace the notation:
$$P(R | B \cap E) = \frac{P(E | B \cap R)P(R | B)}{P(E | B)}$$

At this point we expand the denominator using the Total Probability formula. Recall that for taking total probability over a single event and its complement the formula looks like this:

$$P(X) = P(Y)P(X | Y) + P(Y^c)P(X | Y^c)$$

Similarly to the above, the total probability formula still holds if all the probabilities are replaced by conditional probabilities on $B$:

$$P(E | B) = P(R | B)P(E | R \cap B) + P(R^c | B)P(E | R^c \cap B) $$

On substituting this into the denominator the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an application of the Law for Total Probability under the condition of $B$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R\mid B\cap E) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\cap E\cap R)}{\mathsf P(B\cap E)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\cap E\cap R)}{\mathsf P(B\cap E\cap R)+\mathsf P(B\cap E\cap R^\complement)}\\[2ex] &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(R\mid B)~\mathsf P(E\mid B\cap R)}{\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(R\mid B)~\mathsf P(E\mid B\cap R)+\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(R^\complement\mid B)~\mathsf P(E\mid B\cap R^\complement)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(R\mid B)~\mathsf P(E\mid B\cap R)}{\mathsf P(R\mid B)~\mathsf P(E\mid B\cap R)+\mathsf P(R^\complement \mid B)~\mathsf P(E\mid B\cap R^\complement)}\end{align}$$